# Google Cloud Platform: Hiding Billing "widget" from dashboard for some users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to hide the billing widget from some users in the GCP console?

I know if I login as myself, I can customize my dashboard, but I need to hide the billing widget from a couple of users (long story) so I'm looking for guidance.

Another option would be to create some sort of "default" dashboard for everyone, which would not include the billing widget, that would work too if someone knows how to do that.

Thanks...Rich

Comment: I believe the widget is called the "billing card"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to remove that Billing card for all users. If you remove it on your dashboard, it is only hidden on yours. The default dashboard is the same for all users.

On top of that, the same permissions that allow users to access the Management Console also provides permissions to see the contents of that card. At the moment, the only way to hide the contents of that card is to remove access to the console as a whole.

This being said, there is currently a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/74068850) in progress to have special permissions created for the billing card or to include that billing info in the Cloud Billing account (which can be restricted on a per user basis)